# Flex : Is it possible to stop a remote call?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, amf

I search for a long time, but I still not found the answer.

In common case, we keep the token of a remote method call, Flex -> Java for example.
But, if the client know that the current call is not needed anymore, how stopping the server processing ?

With an asyncToken, is it possible to stop a remote call ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood it, an AsyncToken just provides extra data for some operation.  You'll need to access that operation to cancel.

IF you're calling an [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html), you use the [cancel()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#cancel%28%29) method.

If you're using a [WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html), you should be able to call [getOperation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html#getOperation%28%29) method and then [cancel()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractInvoker.html#cancel%28%29) the corresponding operation.

If you're using a [RemoteObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html) you should be able to call [getOperation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html#getOperation%28%29) method and then [cancel()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractInvoker.html#cancel%28%29) on the corresponding operation.