# Flex - how to abort/stop a RemoteObject method call?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, remoteobject

I am using RemoteObjects to call ZendAMF PHP from Flex/Flash Builder 4.6.  I want to stop or abort a method call before it sends the request to the server based on an event or similar.

I have a class where I create and store all the RemoteObjects - for example:

```
activityLogService = new RemoteObject("zend");
activityLogService.endpoint=endpointServer;
activityLogService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,faultHandler);
```

Then later I can simply call this object:

```
remotingService.activityLogService .getRecords();
```

I am trying to find a way in my remotingService object to stop the request - and not send anything to the server - for example if some variables are not set properly.

I noticed there is an invoke event:
activityLogService.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE,invokeHandler);

However, I can not tell if that's going to stop things at the proper point, or if it's even possible to actually STOP the request - if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question 
[Flex : Is it possible to stop a remote call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365165/flex-is-it-possible-to-stop-a-romote-call/9365696#9365696)

> If you're using a [RemoteObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html) you should be able to call
>   [getOperation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html#getOperation%28%29) method and then [cancel()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractInvoker.html#cancel%28%29) on the corresponding
>   operation.

Comment: That's close, but what I am looking for is to block the operation before it is able to send anything.  I think with what you are suggesting the getOperation would potentially start to connect and could even complete before a cancel() is called?

Comment: If you want to cancel something before it starts; why don't you just set a Boolean flag (AKA CallService) and then check that flag before initiating the call? (if CallService == true){ remoteObject.send() }

Comment: your answer is intriguing, but I am not completely sure what you mean - for example, when I call: remotingService.activityLogService.getRecords();    ".getRecords()" is the remote method on the php side.    So I am not sure where I would on the flex side put the if() part.

Comment: @ScottSzretter I'm not sure which "IF()" part you're referring to; as I don't make mention of any conditionals in this answer nor the one I linked to.

Comment: (if CallService == true) in your comment

Comment: @ScottSzretter Oh, I get it.  You'd wrap the call in an if; like this if(callService == true) { ( remotingService.activityLogService.getRecords()) }