# Is it possible to cancel an RPC Call?

Tags: apache-flex, rpc, asynctoken

Is it possible to cancel an RPC call that is assigned to an AsyncToken with responders?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex : Is it possible to stop a romote call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365165/flex-is-it-possible-to-stop-a-romote-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the AsyncToken has a reference to the [Operation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractOperation.html) in the [IMessage Body](http://www.eonflex.com/flex/4.1/langref/mx/messaging/messages/IMessage.html#body). If not, you'll need to add [it manually](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html#getOperation%28%29).  I don't think you can cancel a specific call this way--it looks like it would only cancel the most recent.

Comment: I see. The problem is that when multiple calls to the same operation are called they sometimes overlap and so the first call isn't always the first to return a result. And so I want to cancel any call on the same AsyncToken or operation when a result is received.

Comment: Potentially, you could extend Operation and AsyncToken to do what you want.

Comment: I considered doing that or even simpler, have a control variable that tells the app weather or not to do something with the freshly received data. I was just looking to see if there's an out-of-the-box way of doing this. Thank you.